# Programmatically create a full page screen shot of a given website with Chrome 59

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

I want to be able to create a pull page screen shot of a given website, but the website may be larger than can be viewed on the screen. Is there a way I can do it programmatically with the help of new Chrome 59 and latest chromedirver if i use Selenium Webdriver?

Comment: @JeffC it's a perfectly valid question with needs an answer. If it's a duplicate post just link the right thing.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren I never said it wasn't a valid question but there are rules and expectations on SO. No links, no references, no code. With your rep, you should know this. SO is not for "give me teh codez" questions.

Comment: @JeffC I know that SO isn't the community it once was. We used to thrive on just solving problems.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren I love solving problems but what I've found is I spend a lot of time coming up with a solution to a poorly defined question after a best guess at what they intended and the answer is not useful because they've already tried that approach or it won't work because of X or whatever. If people want help from the SO community, they need to spend a basic amount of effort in researching their own problem. It's better for them because they have the opportunity to learn on their own and solve their own problems. It's also better for us because we can focus on a clearly defined problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Nightmare.js](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare)?

Here's an [example](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/328) from one of the [authors](https://github.com/rosshinkley):

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare'),
    vo = require('vo');

function * run() {
    var nightmare = new Nightmare({
        show: false,
        width: 1024,
        height: 768
    });
    var dimensions = yield nightmare.goto('http://www.gmail.com')
        .wait('body')
        .evaluate(function() {
            var body = document.querySelector('body');
            return { 
                height: body.scrollHeight,
                width:body.scrollWidth
            }
        });

    console.dir(dimensions);
    yield nightmare.viewport(dimensions.width, dimensions.height)
        .wait(1000)
        .screenshot(require('path')
            .join(__dirname, 'gmail.png'));

    yield nightmare.end();
}   

vo(run)(function() {
    console.log('done');
});
```

Comment: No, it didn't work for me. And want to take screenshot from chrome browser. I am not sure if there is some solution with new release for chrome browser.

Comment: Nightmare.js uses Electron, which is built on top of Chrome - https://electron.atom.io/docs/faq/#when-will-electron-upgrade-to-latest-chrome

Answer (score -1):

No, unfortunately such thing is not possible.